# C# How to convert Environment.TickCount into HH:mm:ss:ms

Tags: c#, int, valueconverter

I'm trying to convert an int value Environment.TickCount into a format dd:HH:mm:ss:ms (days:hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds)

Is there an easy way to do it or should I divide Environment.TickCount by 60 then by 3600 then by 216000, etc ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd use a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeSpan.aspx) structure and in particular [the FromMilliseconds static method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.frommilliseconds.aspx):

```
var timespan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount);
```

then you have all the values you want and you can use the various `ToString` options as well, namely something like

```
timespan.ToString("dd:hh:mm:ss:ff")
```

Check out [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) for the custom `TimeSpan` string formats.